# Transcluent BDSF render problem

Tags: rendering, shaders

I am a beginner in blender, there is a little problem with rendering: When I add Transcluent BDSF, the leaves of the tree become white-edged. How can this problem be solved? Can you help please?
[image]

Comment: Hi :). The translucent shader doesn't support transparency directly. You need to add another mix shader to mix it in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm making a tree like in the tutorial, but that guy didn't add any other shaders. I added a mix shader but now the leaves are disappear

Answer (score 1):

You need to mix the Transparency in.
The Translucent shader doesn't support it by itself.

<sup>It'll be way simpler when they finally add translucency into the Principled shader.</sup>

[image]